# Can I animate innerHTML of a div using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css-animations

I have these "cell" divs in an html file:

```
<div data-spaces class="cell"></div>
```

They have a dynamic content so that onclick, the innerHTML changes from "" to "X".

```
const gridSpaces = document.querySelectorAll("[data-spaces]");

for(let i = 0; i < gridSpaces.length; i++) {

    gridSpaces[i].addEventListener("click", () => {

        gridSpaces[i].innerHTML = "X";
    });
}
```

I want to have an animation effect when the innerHTML changes on the div, [like this](https://playtictactoe.org/)

I've tried adding animations in the css to the "cell" class, but the animation works for the "cell" divs, and not for the content:

```
.cell {
    animation: shake 0.5s;
}
```

How can I make a CSS animation so that when the innerHTML changes, I get a little zoom in like in the above link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select text nodes in the CSS and use animations for them. But if you can control the `innerHTML` of cells, you can create wrapper elements around the cell content:

```js
const gridSpaces = document.querySelectorAll("[data-spaces]");

for(let i = 0; i < gridSpaces.length; i++) {

    gridSpaces[i].addEventListener("click", () => {

        gridSpaces[i].innerHTML = "<div class=\"content\">X</div>";
    });
}
```

```css
@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.content {
    animation: shake 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div data-spaces class="cell"></div>
<div data-spaces class="cell"></div>
<div data-spaces class="cell"></div>
```

Comment: This worked nicely, thanks. I made my Xs shake. Any clues on how to animate a zoom in CSS?

Comment: Found an answer to zoom-in animation here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907250/zoom-in-zoom-out-img-automatically-using-css-only

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add a new class after the innerHTML have been updated. So animation will start correctly when the class will be added.

```css
.cell.animate {
    animation: shake 0.5s;
}
```

```js
const gridSpaces = document.querySelectorAll("[data-spaces]");

for(let i = 0; i < gridSpaces.length; i++) {

    gridSpaces[i].addEventListener("click", () => {

        gridSpaces[i].innerHTML = "X";
        gridSpaces[i].classList.add("animate");

    });
}
```